# Getting null when using the string outside the interface

Tags: java, android, interface, android-alertdialog

I have created a method in which i have displayed an alert on button click.I have create also created a interface to get the text on the button and also its position.Now in my other class when i am using that method i always get an null pointer on the string.

Alertmethod

```
protected void displayPopup(Context context, String title, final String[] array, final Button button, final boolean setText, final GetNamePosition getNamePosition) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    button.setText(array[i]);


                getNamePosition.getName(button.getText().toString());
                getNamePosition.getPosition(i);

                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
```

Other Class where i am using the popup

```
private String[] chooseDocumentArray;
    private String userSelection;
case R.id.bt_choose_file:

                displayPopup(getActivity(), "Choose File", chooseDocumentArray, btChooseDoc, false, new GetNamePosition() {
                    @Override
                    public void getName(String name) {
                        userSelection = name;
                        if (userSelection.equals("Gallery")) {
                            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void getPosition(int position) {

                    }
                });

//                if (userSelection.equals("Gallery")) {
//                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
//                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
//                }

        }
```

Interface

```
public interface GetNamePosition {

    public void getName(String name);

    public void getPosition(int position);
}
```

wehn i am using the string userselection inside the interface the app works fine,but when i use it outside the interface{one which i have commented}i get force close

Answer (score 0):

The userSelection is initialized only in the getName method and its value its value is null otherwise.

To avoid getting a null pointer, try this `private String userSelection = "";` or
put a null check before using the string outside the interface i.e

```java
if(userSelection != null){
     if (userSelection.equals("Gallery")) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
     }
}
```

Comment: ya now i am not getting null pointer, but now the gallery open but itself without the user selecting the gallery

Comment: the same code now i have removed the gallery intent from the interface and uncommented the outside code

Comment: Gallery might be opening due to some other parts in your code. Make sure to use break in switch cases at the end of each case. cannot figure out the exact problem due to lack of complete code mate.